# How to use calendar in my application

Tags: android, calendar

I want to use calendar in my Android application in grid view format and it will show events and images on a specific date.

Is there any calendar view that I could use?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-provider-tests/source/browse/trunk/src/com/androidbook/androidcalendar/CalendarActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) in the SDK but it's available since API level 11 (Android 3.0).

If you need your app to run in previous versions, too, you can try [this open-source project](http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/).